# Place a character in the middle of every word in VIM

Tags: vim

I have a file wth multiple lines that look like

```
RUS.LEN.8 "0612" "1212" "0605" "0606" "0000" "2121" "0401" "1211" "0000" "0707" "0000" "0000" "1111" "0303" "0303" "0102" "0133" "0602" "0000" "0404" "1212" "1111" "0000" "0101" "0000" "0909" "0103" "1010" "1515" "0000"
```

I want to place a / in the middle of every 4 numbers block, using VIM.  Any idea how?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried :s/"../"..\//. but that changes the first two numbers to dots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To turn `0612` into `06/12`, *capture* the first and last two digits separately, then recombine them in the replacement with a `/` in between. With `:substitute`'s `g` flag, this will be applied to *all* matches of a line. With the `:%` range, the command will apply to *every* line in the buffer.

```
:%substitute#\(\d\d\)\(\d\d\)#\1/\2#g
```

#### Notes

- The default separator is `/`, which is also used literally in your replacement. One could escape that (`\/`), but a more readable trick is to use a different delimiter (here: `#`).
- Each *capture group* (`\(...\)`) is referred to by its number in the replacement: `\1`, `\2` and so on. See `:help s/\1`.
- You'll find much more details (on regular expressions, and the syntax) under `:help :s`.

Answer (score 1):

For such a substitution you can use

:%s/"[0-9]{2}/&//g
[image]